# Can I have an optional parameter for an ASP.NET SOAP web service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, optional-parameters

I want to build a webservice with this signature, which does not throw an exception if param2 is left empty. Is this possible?

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld(string param1, bool param2) { }
```

The exception is a System.ArgumentException that is thrown when trying to convert the empty string to boolean.

Ideas that have not worked so far:

- method overloading is not allowed for webservices, like

  ```
  public string HelloWorld(string param1)
  {
      return HelloWorld(param1, false);
  }
  ```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155826/best-way-of-making-an-argument-optional-for-a-c-webmethod):

- make `bool` nullable `bool?`. Same exception.
- manipulate the WSDL, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156498/how-to-set-minoccurs-to-1/1156574#1156574)

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995521/asp-net-web-service-optional-parameters), but the only answer points to WCF contracts, which I have not used yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have a Overloaded Method in webservices with MessageName attribute. This is a workaround to achieve the overloading functionality.

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28VS.71%29.aspx

```
[WebMethod(MessageName="Add3")]
public double Add(double dValueOne, double dValueTwo, double dValueThree)
{
   return dValueOne + dValueTwo + dValueThree;
}

[WebMethod(MessageName="Add2")]
public int Add(double dValueOne, double dValueTwo)
{
   return dValueOne + dValueTwo;
}
```

The methods will be made visible as `Add2` and `Add3`to the outside.

Comment: Will both methods look like the same one to the outside world?

Comment: Hauke, 

No, It will two different methods to outside world. This is a workaround for Overloading.

Answer (score 15):

If you *REALLY* have to accomplish this, here's a ***sort of hack*** for the specific case of a web method that has only primitive types as parameters:

```
[WebMethod]
public void MyMethod(double requiredParam1, int requiredParam2)
{
    // Grab an optional param from the request.
    string optionalParam1 = this.Context.Request["optionalParam1"];

    // Grab another optional param from the request, this time a double.
    double optionalParam2;
    double.TryParse(this.Context.Request["optionalParam2"], out optionalParam2);
    ...
}
```

Comment: not work! this.Context.Request["optionalParam1"] always returns null

Comment: This is the answer for Missing Parameter problem in WebMethod. Good Work

Answer (score 7):

I know this post is little old. But I think the method names should be same for the example from Rasik. If both method names are same, then where overloading comes there. I think it should be like this:

```
[WebMethod(MessageName="Add3")]
public double Add(double dValueOne, double dValueTwo, double dValueThree)
{
   return dValueOne + dValueTwo + dValueThree;
}

[WebMethod(MessageName="Add2")]
public int Add(double dValueOne, double dValueTwo)
{
   return dValueOne + dValueTwo;
}
```

Comment: Yes I was wondering about that too - otherwise why bother with different method names.  I shall propose this as an edit to his answer.

Answer (score 3):

In accordance with [MinOccurs Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c(v=vs.80).aspx#Anchor_2) and [Default Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d1es9ye(v=vs.80).aspx#Anchor_3):

1. Value type accompanied by a public bool field that uses the Specified naming convention described previously under Translating XSD to source - minOccurs value of output `<element>` element 0.

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public SomeResult SomeMethod(bool optionalParam, [XmlIgnore] bool optionalParamSpecified)
   ```

   result:

   ```
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="optionalParam" type="s:boolean" />
   ```
2. Value type with a default value specified via a System.Component.DefaultValueAttribute - minOccurs value of output `<element>` element 0. In the `<element>` element, the default value is also specified via the default XML attribute.

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public SomeResult SomeMethod([DefaultValue(true)] bool optionalParam)
   ```

   result:

   ```
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" default="true" name="optionalParam" type="s:boolean" />
   ```

Comment: [DefaultValue(true)] works well for properties as well

Answer (score 1):

You can not have overloaded Web Service methods. The SOAP protocol does not support it. Rasik's code is the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Making your parameter `bool?` and having your caller send an explicit null also works as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best solution that has proven to work for me.

- Don't bother creating function overloads.
- Don't use different name for functions.
- Don't use optional parameters.
- Don't use this solution either
  [Web Service Method with Optional Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565842/web-service-method-with-optional-parameters)

Simply have a data class with all your desired parameters as properties and simply have that class as the only parameter. This way every property of the class will be serialized optionally and will the default value if it was not passed in.

Here is what I am talking about

```
[Serializable]
public class DataObj
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod(MessageName = "MyMethod")]
public void MyMethod(DataObj dataObj)
{}
```

Comment: Anytime you need a new parameter to work with, simply add it to the DataObj as a new property and if service caller does not send it, it will simply have the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Make all optional arguments strings. If no argument is passed, the input is treated as null.

Comment: This works (if parameter was missing from the calling side it comes as Nothing). Tnx !