# Calling a C# webmethod using jquery ajax omitting optional parameters

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a webmethod like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string testMethod(string param1, string param2="default value")
{
    .......
}
```

I am trying to callthis method using jquery omitting the optional parameter, and the webmethod doesn't get hit.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: { "param1": "value1" }
}).complete(function (data) {....});
```

I works only when I pass the second parameter also. Is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have an optional parameter for an ASP.NET SOAP web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723052/can-i-have-an-optional-parameter-for-an-asp-net-soap-web-service)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can use *Optional Params* with webservice methods, you'll probably need to Overload the method...

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true, MessageName = "testMethod"))]
public string testMethod(string param1, string param2)
{
      .......
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true, MessageName = "testMethod")]
public string testMethod(string param1)
{
      testMethod(param1, "default value");
}
```

**EDIT**: Article Link.

There's also an [article here](http://mariuszrokita.wordpress.com/2012/01/20/asmx-and-optional-arguments/) worth reading for additional approaches, and although it concludes not to use *Overloading*, I guess it's your decision.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am planning to do now. Just curious to know if we can do it without method overloading

Comment: @Sharun, I added a link to an article, see edit.  I don't think you can actually, we did look at it in work too and came up with the same solution.

Comment: I thinkk you should use different `MessageName` on each method , because while I used same name it doesnt work but using different names it works.

Comment: @TarıkÖzgünGüner, I mention that at the end with regards to _overloading_