# How to add more parameters to a JSON WebService without breaking call from old clients?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, soap

I want to add more parameters to my **JSON WebService** without breaking call from old clients.
Example:

My WebService in **Service.asmx**

```
[WebMethod]
public string Ping(string msg, string additionalInfo)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(additionalInfo))
    {
        return "Process msg with old version";
    }
    return "Process msg with new version"; ;
}

//My old web service does not have additionalInfo arguments
//public string Ping(string msg) {..}
```

**Web.config** tells that **my WebService is JSON-based**

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000" />
       </webServices>
   </scripting>
```

if clients call my new Json WebService with all the parameters => everything is fine

```
CallWs("http://localhost:48918/Service.asmx/Ping", '{"msg":"hello", "additionalInfo":""}')
```

But all the current clients won't give the `additionalInfo`:

```
CallWs("http://localhost:48918/Service.asmx/Ping", '{"msg":"hello"}')
```

my new WebService will immediately return error:

```
string(654) "{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027additionalInfo\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}"
```

So my customers will have to change theire code in order to use my new WebService, I don't want that. I want to give default values to my new WebService, What is the best way to do?

Possible duplication: [Can I have an optional parameter for an ASP.NET SOAP web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723052/can-i-have-an-optional-parameter-for-an-asp-net-soap-web-service)
But none of the response works for me.

---

**FYI**
my customers often call my JSON WebService via PHP, they simply make a POST request to the service endpoint:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost:48918/Service.asmx/Ping");
$wsrq = array(
    "msg" => "Hello",
    //"additionalInfo" => "World",
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($wsrq),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"),
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: try make it optional parameters ? public string Ping(string msg, string additionalInfo=null)

Comment: or write an overloaded function extra in the web service.

Comment: doesn't work! it was the first thing I tried..

Comment: you tried with an overloaded function ?

Comment: i think you can achieve optional parameters by overloads using the MessageName property.

Comment: How is this web service called? I am surprised that adding a parameter will break it, especially if it is a JSON enabled service. What's this `CallWs`  method doing more specifically?

Comment: I don't like the overloaded function, overtime, I will have a lot of version for Ping serivces, I will have a lot of overloaded function Ping1(), Ping2(), Ping3().. which bloated my API, new customer will have to choose between them..

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I added client code in the question. The client make a Post request to the webservice. And the WS doesn't like the missing argument requests..

Comment: Thanks, I am able to reproduce the issue. That got me surprised, honestly I wouldn't have expected this to break. Looks like the only way to achieve that is by using method overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the proper way to achieve that is to use method overloads for your service methods. Also for the future methods I would recommend you using models:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Ping(MyModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

This will give you more flexibility because you will be able to add properties easily in the future without breaking.

This being said, there's one *approach* or a workaround that you might consider: manual deserialization (I totally don't recommend it but worth mentioning).

Make your WebMethod without any parameters:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Ping()
```

and then read the request body manually by accessing the input stream:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Ping()
{
    Context.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using (var inputStream = Context.Request.InputStream)
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
    {
        string body = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // TODO: Worth checking the request headers before attempting JSON deserialization
        // For example the Content-Type header
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(body);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AdditionalInfo))
        {
            return "Process msg with old version";
        }
        return "Process msg with new version"; ;
    }
}
```

To avoid mixing multiple responsibilities in your service method you could move the parsing of the body stream into some separate extension method:

```
public static class RequestExtensions
{
    public static T ParseRequest<T>(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var inputStream = request.InputStream)
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
        {
            string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(body);
        }
    }
}
```

and then your WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Ping()
{
    var model = Context.Request.ParseRequest<MyModel>();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AdditionalInfo))
    {
        return "Process msg with old version";
    }
    return "Process msg with new version"; ;
}
```

Now clients can call the Ping method like that:

```
POST /WebService1.asmx/Ping HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:14529
Content-Length: 61

{
    "msg": "Hello",
    "additionalInfo": "add info"
}
```

or the old way:

```
POST /WebService1.asmx/Ping HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:14529
Content-Length: 26

{
    "msg": "Hello"
}
```

Comment: change from Ping(string) to Ping(MyModel) is also a breaking changes we want to avoid. But it seems there is no better way. thanks

Comment: Yes, I know that it is breaking change. I mentioned it for your V2. So that you can easily do V3 at a later stage. In all cases you should definitely consider migrating away from this deprecated technology which is what classic ASP.NET webservices represent now.